# How to dump a yaml.MappingNode or a yaml.ScalarNode preserving the tag?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Given a python structure like the following:

```py
from yaml import ScalarNode, MappingNode

my_obj = {
'test': ScalarNode(tag='!my_tag1', value='test_value'),
'a': MappingNode(tag='!my_tag2', value=[(ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value='b'), ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value='1')), (ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value='c'), ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value='1'))])} 
}
```

I'd like to obtain the related ".yml" file without any tag parsing. The desired output is:

```yaml
test: !my_tag1 test_value
a: !my_tag2
    b: 1
    c: 1
```

The easy way would have been:
`yaml.safe_dump(my_obj)`

But of course in this way I get the error:

```py
RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', MappingNode(tag='!my_tag2', value=[(ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value='b'), ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value='1')), (ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value='c'), ScalarNode(tag='tag:yaml.org,2002:int', value='1'))]))
```

What is the correct way to define a "representer" that "dumps" a generic yaml Node preserving the tag and the value?

Comment: PyYAML cannot safe_dump arbitrar objects and those include`Node` subclasses that it uses internally. You'll need to read the [documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#nodes) and use `serialize`.  The officially recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. Or you use my `ruamel.yaml` where you can set tags on its types that dump to mappings/scalars including tag information (using a  normal dump and having a meaningful behaviour)